# Tag shenanigans: "datatable" vs "datatables"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

There's a [jQuery plugin named DataTables](http://datatables.net/). There's a [.NET class named DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx).

There are SO tags named [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) and [datatable](/questions/tagged/datatable), both of which describe the jQuery DataTables plugin.

A number of posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350326/asplinqdatasource-datatable), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346161/improve-datatable-readxml-performance), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335055/table-rendering-problem-in-browser) are good examples) are tagged [datatable](/questions/tagged/datatable) and use the .NET DataTable, yet there's the occasional question (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316579/best-way-to-add-hidden-data-to-cell-in-datatables-net) which is tagged [datatable](/questions/tagged/datatable) and actually refer to the jQuery DataTables.

Similarly, there are .NET DataTable questions that are tagged [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298239/how-to-update-the-values-from-datatable-to-datagridview-using-c-net)).

To throw more confusion into the loop there's also a [Yahoo UI plugin named DataTable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/), which is seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305512/yui-datatable-query-xml-for-specific-data).

It's all so convoluted.

How's this for a solution: jQuery DataTables questions go under [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables), .NET DataTable questions go under [datatable](/questions/tagged/datatable), and YUI DataTable questions go under... uh, I dunno, [yui-datatable](/questions/tagged/yui-datatable)?

Whatever happens, [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) and [datatable](/questions/tagged/datatable) should not be synonyms, even if their info pages seem to suggest they are (and I think I'm going to go edit the [datatable](/questions/tagged/datatable) info page after this).

Comment: The tags should probably be split and prefixed: `.net-datatable`, `jquery-datatables`, `yui-datatable`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking too, but I wasn't sure what the protocol was surrounding prefixes. Then would `datatable` be a synonym of `.net-datatable`, etc.?

Comment: To add to the confusion, the home of the jQuery plugin is `datatables.net`

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest [jquery-datatables](/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) for the jQuery plugin. It fits the convention that seems to be used for jQuery plugin tags such as: [jquery-isotope](/questions/tagged/jquery-isotope), [jquery-masonry](/questions/tagged/jquery-masonry), [jquery-cycle](/questions/tagged/jquery-cycle), etc.

The *-plugin* suffix only really gets used in a couple of instances:

- [struts2-jquery-plugin](/questions/tagged/struts2-jquery-plugin) (which apparently coexists with [struts2-jquery](/questions/tagged/struts2-jquery) and should probably be made a synonym)
- [jquery-forms-plugin](/questions/tagged/jquery-forms-plugin) which is just the literal name of [jQuery Forms Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133869/163268), I think the optimal solution, or at least the starting point to end all the confusion, is to make the jquery datatables plugin tag be:

**jquery-datatables-plugin**

Allowing this jquery plugin to be synonymous with "datatables" or even "datatables.net" means the ambiguity will be permanent.

Answer (score 1):

The word "datatable" is widely used in IT, so, in my opinion, the best option is to leave the tag [datatable](/questions/tagged/datatable) and use it for general questions about datatable-like structures.

Questions about jQuery plugin should land to [jquery-datatable](/questions/tagged/jquery-datatable) or [jquery-datatable-plugin](/questions/tagged/jquery-datatable-plugin).

Questions about .NET class should land to [datatable.net](/questions/tagged/datatable.net).

Any questions about specific datatable implementation should have specific tag. For example, for PrimeFaces p:dataTable it should be [primefaces-datatable](/questions/tagged/primefaces-datatable).

The [datatable](/questions/tagged/datatable) tag wiki should be edited as well, to point out, that this tag is for general questions, and implementation-specific questions have own tags.

Comment: I don't think the `.net` suffix is used in tags to refer to classes of the framework. It's only used for projects that have the **.Net** as part of their name.