# Merge datatables and datatables.net tags

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

I think we need only one tag for [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) (the plugin), and right now there are two of them, [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) and [datatables.net](/questions/tagged/datatables.net).
I don't know what's the best one, datatables causes some confusion because of c# datatable, datatables.net is tied to a domain and i don't like that much. 
Anyway, what do you think?

Answer (score 3):

I agree with you completely: as mentioned elsewhere [Tag shenanigans: "datatable" vs "datatables"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105574/tag-shenanigans-datatable-vs-datatables), the datatables tag is not exactly clear in what it means.

The tag name that would make the most sense to me, as regards the jquery plugin, would be:

**jquery-datatables-plugin**

A name like that should hopefully prevent any further confusion. It is also in the same vein as the tag name **jquery-forms-plugin**, which I suppose had to be so verbose so as to avoid any potential confusion (just having **jquery-forms** would have been open to all kinds of interpretation).

It also seems respectful to the plug-in author, since the first description on the [datatables homepage](http://datatables.net/) is:

> DataTables is a plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library. It is a highly flexible tool, based upon the foundations of progressive enhancement, which will add advanced interaction controls to any HTML table.

Answer (score 3):

Currently we seem to have: [jquery-datatables](/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables), [datatables.net](/questions/tagged/datatables.net), [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) and [datatable](/questions/tagged/datatable)

In the current state of affairs, here's what I think we need to do with them.

### Keep these: [jquery-datatables](/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) and [datatable](/questions/tagged/datatable)

[jquery-datatables](/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) should be the jQuery plugin's tag. This follows in line with our convention for jQuery plugin tags: jquery- followed by the plugin's name.

[datatable](/questions/tagged/datatable) can be used to refer to the [.NET DataTable class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx).

We should not use [jquery-forms-plugin](/questions/tagged/jquery-forms-plugin) for the jQuery plugin's tag, since our convention is to only include -plugin on the end when it's actually a part of the plugin's name - for instance, in the case of [jquery-forms-plugin](/questions/tagged/jquery-forms-plugin), which is literally named *jQuery Forms Plugin*.

### Retag then blacklist these: [datatables.net](/questions/tagged/datatables.net) and [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables)

[datatables.net](/questions/tagged/datatables.net) is just the domain name of the site, and it's like having a [jquery.com](/questions/tagged/jquery.com) tag. We don't need this tag.

As [madth3 pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193103/152515), [datatables.net](/questions/tagged/datatables.net) also easily confused with the .NET DataTable. It's ambiguous and confusing. [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) is also ambiguous and confusing, but it is much worse.

- People who use [datatables.net](/questions/tagged/datatables.net) use it for the jQuery plugin ([see this search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables.net+jquery)). However, some also use it [alongside the C# tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables.net+c%23) or [alongside the .NET tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables.net+.net).
- [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) gets the same treatment, but *even worse*. It gets used in [a whole lot of other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables+-jquery+-.net). Arguably, it gets misused in almost every circumstance: it's used for HTML tables, and database tables. It also gets used to ask about the jQuery plugin.

If we keep either of these tags around, even as synonyms, people are going to keep confusing and misusing them. We should give these two tags a cleanup and then blacklist them.

Comment: Well, `[jquery-datatables]` has been created and `[datatables.net]` has been retagged and removed.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have gotten worse, with now tags for [datatable](/questions/tagged/datatable), [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables), and [datatables.net](/questions/tagged/datatables.net) - this needs to be cleaned up, with perhaps [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) and [datatables.net](/questions/tagged/datatables.net) synonyms of [jquery-datatables-plugin](/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables-plugin) ?

Comment: I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

The name of the plugin seems to be just "Datatables". I don't see why `datatables.net` should be used as a tag for the plugin even it's the same as its domain. Particularly since it can generate confusion with the `DataTable` class of .Net.

I think [jquery-datatables](/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) should be used for the plugin and maybe leave [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) as a synonym. [datatables.net](/questions/tagged/datatables.net) should disappear.