# Identically named library in two distinct languages - tag naming precedent?

Tags: support, tags, ambiguous-tags

I was editing a question today and discovered an accidental mis-tagging by the user:

[Create .listing file using use Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18843546/1668057)

The original tag was for [net-sftp](/questions/tagged/net-sftp), a tag which exists for the Ruby **Net::SFTP** module from the Net:SSH library.

What the OP was after was the non-existent tag for the [pure Python implementation](http://search.cpan.org/~dbrobins/Net-SFTP-0.10/lib/Net/SFTP.pm), also conveniently named **Net::SFTP**, which according to [this wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Development) is a `full SFTP client written in Perl with lots of bells and whistles`.

Oh dear, a search for [`[net-sftp] -[ruby] -[ruby-on-rails]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/net-sftp+-ruby+-ruby-on-rails) leads to more questions mis-taggingly using the Ruby one, but also at least [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8888979/1668057) in search of the [PHP implementation of a **Net::SFTP** library](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).

Obviously, what this world needs more than another intervention in the Middle East is more tags - but how to taxonomize all these identically named tools?

Comment: Related: [How to handle tags with multiple meanings?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6928/how-to-handle-tags-with-multiple-meanings)

Comment: Thanks @gnat, I noticed from on example there that they seem to have remedied by putting a disclaimer style message in the tag itself: [smf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smf), which then leads users to the specific/new disambiguous tag. In this case, where there are multiple, might it be effective to create one for each variation needing specific tags, re-tagging the existing and then putting such a message in the original? Hopefully the tag auto-suggestion would suggest the correct `net-sftp-php` or `net-sftp-perl` based on the question's context... still seems complicated though

Comment: how about [net-sftp] with a language tag?

Comment: I think it's a way to go and I'll volunteer to rewrite the tag wiki. Do I have the peoples' blessing?