# Please merge datatables and jquery-datatables tags

Tags: support, retag-request

The [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) and [jquery-datatables](/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables) tags are redundant; their summaries and full [descriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatables/info) are [identical](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-datatables/info). Can they be merged, with [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) recreated as a synonym to [jquery-datatables](/questions/tagged/jquery-datatables)?

Comment: Related: [Tag shenanigans: “datatable” vs “datatables”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105574/152515) and [Merge datatables and datatables.net tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128285/152515)

Comment: I created this question before http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange...should I flag all such stackoverflow-specific meta questions for migration to stackoverflow? I seem to remember there being an age limit, so maybe that's not possible...

Answer (score 6):

Datatables should actually be retagged then blacklisted.

The tag wikis *might* be the same, but [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) gets used for all kinds of things - the jQuery plugin, .NET's DataTable class, database tables, HTML tables, and so on. If we just create a synonym, the jQuery datatables tag will probably have an influx of those questions. I wrote about that [in another answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196373/152515) covering the datatables tag and its companions.

To prevent that, we should probably just blacklist it to have people search for another tag to use instead.

Comment: Even if [tag:datatables] has become a catch-all, since the tag's creation, it's wiki has been unequivocal in it's intention: "DataTables is a plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library..." http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5829962/revisions#spacer-d1aa02c9-fbac-4012-9e61-f27c3e63d97d

Comment: No. I'm providing some information that supports your suggestion to retagg and blacklist.